# How do I keep Cognos from splitting my subgroups across pages?

Tags: reporting, grouping, cognos

I am reporting off of a cube into a crosstab with the results being summarized.  For example:

```
                                   |  Val 1 |  Val 2
----------------------------------------------------
Division 1 | Region 1 | Location 1 |   5.00 |   3.00
           |          |-----------------------------
           |          | Location 2 |   2.00 |   6.00
           |          |-----------------------------
           |          | Reg Sum    |   7.00 |   9.00
           |----------------------------------------
           | Region 2 | Location 1 |   4.00 |   3.00
           |          |-----------------------------
           |          | Location 2 |  12.80 |   7.40
           |          |-----------------------------
           |          | Location 3 |   5.00 |  11.00
           |          |-----------------------------
           |          | Reg Sum    |  21.80 |  21.40
           |----------------------------------------
           | Div Sum               |  28.80 |  30.40
----------------------------------------------------
Division 2 | Region 1 | Location 1 |   3.00 |  12.85
etc...
```

Currently, Cognos is breaking the page in the middle of the Division 1/Region 2 subgroup.  If the whole region subgroup (including summary) doesn't fit on the remainder of the page, I want it to go to the next page.

I've tried pagination at the region and location level.  That has not given me the results I want.  Any ideas as to how I can achieve this?

EDIT: Forgot to mention that this is Cognos 8.4.

Comment: UPDATE: I've read that there is a known bug in 8.x that Pagination across crosstabs doesn't work.  Can anyone verify or refute this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, a litle bit out-dated, but nevertheless here is what worked for me:

1. unlock
2. place a  1x1 table object inside the Regions cell
3. place the regions name inside the table object (just drag it inside
   the table)
4. in the table's paginations properties deselect the option Allow row
   contents to break across pages

you might also need to specify the height of the table object.

Comment: that sounds like a plausible solution.  Unfortunately, I don't work for the same company anymore and can't test it.  You mentioned the only concern that I would have, variable height regions.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Page breaks to achieve this.

In your example, click on Region data item. From Structure menu, click "Set Page Break using Master/Detail". 
That will do the trick.

Please note, for crosstab and chart, report studio creates Page Break using Master/Detail relationship. If you were using List or repeater, then you could use the option of creating page break without Master/Detail relationship.

Please refer to IBM Infocenter for more information on Page Breaks and Page Sets. http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/c8bi/v8r4m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.swg.im.cognos.c8bi.doc/welcome.html

Comment: But won't that break on every Region?  I only want the region to break if it won't completely fit on the page.  If I can get multiple complete regions on the page, I want that.